# Error (NaN) recalling value of form in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript

I'm starting to work on a small single-player roulette simulator in HTML and JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Roulette</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Dank<span id="r">Roulette</span><span id="b">Balance: <span id="money">100</span></span></h1>
<p>Bet Amount: <input type = "text" id="bet"><button id="placebet" onclick="placeBet()">Place Bet</button></p>

<script>
var money = money; // also tried var money=100;

function placeBet() {
  if (bet > money) {
    alert("Invalid Bet");
  } else {
    money = money - bet;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
h1{
font-family:Arial;
color:red;
}

#r{
color:green;
}

#b{
margin-left:5cm;
color:black;
border-style:solid;
}
```

When the button is pressed, the balance shows `NaN`. There is also no alert if the bet amount is higher than your money. I think that it has something to do with the bet amount not being recalled properly using the id "bet".

Comment: HTML and JS dont directly work together. You need to use the DOM js api (exposed via `document`)

Comment: You cant just write `bet` in JavaScript and access the textbox value. You need to get the element of the HTML by using  document.getElementById("bet") and convert the value (which is string) to number. Right now bet is undefined and math operation with undefined return NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting NaN because you don't have bet defined.. so `money = money - bet;` becomes undefined.. you need to do var bet=document.getElementById("bet") to get the value and convert it to number and use it for manipulation..
let me know if you still face issue but its very trivial

```js
var money = document.getElementById("money").innerHTML; // also tried var money=100;
var bet=document.getElementById("bet").value;
function placeBet() {
  if (bet > money) {
    alert("Invalid Bet");
  } else {
    money = money - bet;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Roulette</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Dank<span id="r">Roulette</span><span id="b">Balance: <span id="money">100</span></span></h1>
<p>Bet Amount: <input type = "text" id="bet" value=10><button id="placebet" onclick="placeBet()">Place Bet</button></p>

<script>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution has already been given. But the answer would have been obvious to you if you knew how to use a debugger. So I am not telling you the solution, I am telling you **how to FIND the solution**, so you can be autonomous.

Put your **scripts in a separate file** and link them using a script tag.

```
<script src="My_Code_In_Same_Folder_As_HTML.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Then get yourself the **Chrome browser**. And learn to use the debugger that pops
up when you press **F12**.